# Automated way to get packages and their tags in GitHub

Tags: github, curl, pycharm, github-api, pygithub

So im trying to find a way that will best suit a periodic way to verify my Helm files are using the latest package version thats end state.

I found Github has an API to list packages in an org and then a way to get packages details. So first step Id like to be able to pull the package list and then get latest versions tags into a databse or csv file. Looking to automate it so I went python to use pygithub but cant seem to find the same api calls.

Any help with the correct python package to make the same calls as I can with curl through cmd. Or is there a better automated way im not considering that maybe more efficient?

Using these curl calls per this documentation works but wanted to find a better automated way to cause I would need to repeat the second call multiple times once for every package in the org and then im sure a database for all the versions to get it down to the latest one. Using pandas in python for that ideally.

These are the api calls im using so I know they work just cant find their counterpart in pygithub
1st step
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/packages/packages?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-packages-for-an-organization

2nd step
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/packages/packages?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-package-versions-for-a-package-owned-by-an-organization

I have used curl in cmd and am getting the results but its very manual. Id need to automate it to pull multiple packages names api calls. Cant find this call in pygithub.